# Transition from an animation to another animation

Tags: css, animation

I'm not sure how to describe it, so look at this example:

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
               $('.spinner').addClass('paused');
});
```

```css
.spinner {
}

.spinner > div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #9f9f9f;

  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
  animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

.spinner.paused > div {
  -webkit-animation: sk-pause 1.4s 1 ease-in-out both;
  animation: sk-pause 1.4s 1 ease-in-out both;
  // -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  // animation-play-state: paused;
}
.spinner .bounce1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.spinner .bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.3) }
  40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
}
@keyframes sk-pause {
  80%, 100% {transform: scale(0.3)}
}
@keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
  } 40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spinner">
              <div class="bounce1"></div>
              <div class="bounce2"></div>
              <div class="bounce3"></div>
 </div>

<button> Click </button>
```

You have three balls, that are bouncing. When you click the button it adds a class paused, which animates to the smallest visible ball. But when you click, they all come from 1.0 scale to 0.3 scale. I would like that they transition from their previous state to 0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this:

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .spinner {
        }

            .spinner > div {
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
                background-color: #9f9f9f;
                border-radius: 100%;
                display: inline-block;
                -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
                animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
            }

            .spinner.paused > div {
                -webkit-animation: sk-pause 1.4s 1 ease-in-out both;
                animation: sk-pause 1.4s 1 ease-in-out both;
            }

            .spinner .bounce1 {
                -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
                animation-delay: -0.32s;
            }

            .spinner .bounce2 {
                -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
                animation-delay: -0.16s;
            }

        @-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
            0%, 80%, 100% {
                -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
            }

            40% {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
            }
        }

        @keyframes sk-pause {
            80%, 100% {
                transform: scale(0.3);
            }
        }

        @keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
            0%, 80%, 100% {
                -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
                transform: scale(0.3);
            }

            40% {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
                transform: scale(1.0);
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="spinner">
        <div id="div1" class="bounce1"></div>
        <div id="div2" class="bounce2"></div>
        <div id="div3" class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="a" value="Pause" />
    <script>
        $('#a').click(function ()
        {
            var computedStyle1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div1"));
            var computedStyle1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div1"));
        var computedStyle2 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div2"));
        var computedStyle3 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div3"));
        $('#div1').css('transform', computedStyle1.transform).css('-webkit-transform', computedStyle1.transform);
        $('#div2').css('transform', computedStyle2.transform).css('-webkit-transform', computedStyle2.transform);
        $('#div3').css('transform', computedStyle3.transform).css('-webkit-transform', computedStyle3.transform);
            $('.spinner').addClass('paused');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I do not know what is React but I think the code must be some think like this (instead of `$('#a').click(function ()....` block code):

```
$('#a').on('click', () => {
            var computedStyle1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div1"));
            var computedStyle2 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div2"));
            var computedStyle3 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div3"));
            $('#div1').css('transform', computedStyle1.transform).css('-webkit-transform', computedStyle1.transform);
            $('#div2').css('transform', computedStyle2.transform).css('-webkit-transform', computedStyle2.transform);
            $('#div3').css('transform', computedStyle3.transform).css('-webkit-transform', computedStyle3.transform);
            $('.spinner').addClass('paused');
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand the difference. Also using advanced jquery is not going to happen,I'm using react

Comment: You say it does not have difference? Could you please reload that?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Anyway how can I do that using React?

Comment: So Sorry, I had a foolish mistake. I edited that, However it may not help you. Why you want using react? Isn't it possible to do the same as this?

Comment: I write the codes in your React button click block. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok thanks! as  far as i understand, there no CSS-only way to do that :/ For react, it out of the scope of this question anyway